# Fazendo uma div reaparecer

Tags: javascript, html, css

Na div amarela (`id="conteudo"`) há a div rosa (`id="conteudo-interno"`) e uma imagem.
O botão faz com que a div amarela seja limpa, porém gostaria que sumisse tudo, exceto a div rosa (`conteudo-interno`) 
Tem como eu guardar essa div em algum lugar e depois só chama-la para ela aparecer novamente?

```js
function limpaConteudo() {
  $('.conteudo').empty(); 
}
```

```css
#conteudo{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#conteudo-interno{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#f1f;  
    float:left;
    display: initial;
    margin: 50 50;     
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">       </script> <!-- Biblioetca JQuery -->
  </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="limpaConteudo()"> Press Here </button>
  <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo">
   <img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2">
   <div id="conteudo-interno"> Hello World! </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia usar um $('#conteudo img').hide() para desaparecer e um $('#conteudo img').show()  para voltar. Se o objetivo for somente esconder.

Comment: Então, é que nesse exemplo seria só uma imagem, mas em um caso real poderia ser diversas imagens entende? Aí creio que o correto seria apagar

Comment: @sora o conteúdo da sua div rosa é dinâmico ? se for algumas solução com conteúdo pré definido não te atenderão

Comment: Então, para a resolução do problema @Caique eu usei os princípios da resposta do @Felipe, onde usei a `.html`: 
  function limpaConteudo() {
   $('.conteudo').empty();
   $('.conteudo').html('<div id="conteudo-interno"> Hello World! </div>');
  }

Comment: Entendido, veja a minha resposta tentei demonstrar que é possível armazenar o conteúdo mesmo se ele variar, no comentário acima se você fizer uma alteração na divRosa(conteudo-interno) automaticamente você teria que editar a linha $('.conteudo').html('<div id="conteudo-interno"> Hello World! </div>'); causando uma repetição desnecessária.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução abaixo é similar a do [@Felipe Avezani](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/92176/felipe-avezani) com a diferença de que a divRosa é salva no momento em que é solicitado a limpeza do conteúdo, ou seja, capturo o valor dela naquele momento, permitindo a restauração de um conteúdo que varia.

Imagine que você teve que alterar o conteúdo da divRosa, da forma como está a resposta atual você teria que editar ela no `html` e no `javascript` causando retrabalho.

No exemplo abaixo eu coloquei um `input` na divRosa, note que se você limpar e restaurar o conteúdo depois o valor digitado será mantido.

```js
var divRosa;
function limpaConteudo() {
  divRosa = $("#conteudo-interno"); //Salvo a div rosa
  $("#conteudo").empty();
}

function restauraDivRosa(){
  $("#conteudo").html(divRosa);
}
```

```css
#conteudo{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#conteudo-interno{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#f1f;  
    float:left;
    display: initial;
    margin: 50 50;     
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">       </script> <!-- Biblioetca JQuery -->
  </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="limpaConteudo()"> Limpa </button>
    <button onclick="restauraDivRosa()"> Restaura </button>
  <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo">
   <img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2">
   <div id="conteudo-interno"> Hello World! 
        <input type="text" name="teste" value="" />
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Entendi !!, bem melhor mesmo, assim não preciso fazer a repetição do comando `.html`, valeu @Caique pela aula !!

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
  $('#conteudo img').hide()
})

$('#back').on('click', function(){
  $('#conteudo img').show()
})
```

```css
#conteudo{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ff1;  
    display: initial;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#conteudo-interno{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#f1f;  
    float:left;
    display: initial;
    margin: 50 50;     
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">       </script> <!-- Biblioetca JQuery -->
  </head>
 <body>
  <button id="btn"> Press Here </button>
    <button id="back">Voltar</button>
  <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo">
   <img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" class="img">
<img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" class="img">
<img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" class="img">
<img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" class="img">
   <div id="conteudo-interno"> Hello World! </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Seria mais ou menos isso?

AT. Para esconder varias imagens (ou ate mesmo conteudo, div e etc), basta voce ter a classe `img`, que pode ser nomeada com outro nome, por exemplo `ocultar` e definir essa classe em todos os conteudos que quer esconder com o click, dessa maneira, irá fazer um trabalho só

Comment: Perfeito, era só essa parte de manter a div rosa !!! 
Muito obg, vou estudar este código agora

Comment: @Sora se a resposta resolve seu problema, marque como resolvido. Qualquer duvida estamos a disposição.

Comment: Certo, neste caso você apenas escondeu a imagem certo??
É que em um caso real eu poderia ter diversas imagens, creio que o correto seria limpa-las da div mesmo...
Para eu clicar em resolver tenho que esperar 15 minutos

Comment: @Sora na verdade não, se voce quiser mostra-las novamente, tera que recoloca-las, vou editar o codigo para ver o funcionamento com varias imagens

Comment: Ah sim, entendi !! vou usar esta parte de esconder e mostrar novamente 
as imagens em outro módulo, já vou estudando ela, valeu pela ajuda Rafa !!

Comment: @Sora de nada, estamos sempre ai ;)

Answer (score 2):

Para sumir tudo menos a div rosa você deve clonar a div rosa e recria-la fora do DOM do elemento ou tirar a div rosa do elemento conteúdo para que ela não seja apagada. Ou fazer algo assim

```
function limpaConteudo() {
  $('.conteudo').empty();
  $('.conteudo').html('<div id="conteudo-interno"> Hello World! </div>');
}
```

Comment: Entendi, posso clona-la e recria-la chamando o clone... ou posso tira-la do elemento conteúdo, é isso??

Comment: Perfeito !! Obrigado @Felipe pela ajuda !

Comment: sim ou ainda vc limpa tudo e recoloca a info dentro do elemento usando o `html();`

Comment: posta como vc resolveu isto depois

Comment: Esse jeito que você colocou é perfeito, pois limpa todas as imagens e chama a div conteudo interno novamente, vou usar ela.
Pois das outras formas terei de estuda-las e esconder as imagens creio que não seria o correto, pois imagine em um caso onde tem várias imagens entende?

Comment: rss legau , so nao esquece de pontuar minha resp ^^